# What's the usage and behaviour of w:majority on half cluster down?

Tags: mongodb

considering a replica set composed of 5 members :

- R1,R2,R3,R4 being replicas
- A1 being an arbiter

If we use w:majority as write concern in our application :

- How many replicas will be used before ack write when all members are up and running ?
- If 2 replicas out of 4 crash, how is handled 'majority' requirement :

  - does it mean we still wait for write completion on the same number of replicas, meaning the write is blocked, waiting for a members to turn on.
  - does arbiter as an effet on this particular writeConcern and downsize the number of replicas required to satisfy w:majority writeConcern ?

I understand replication w: but majority seems to be a special case :
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#write-operations-write-concern
"For the purposes of write concern, majority refers to a majority of the votes in the set. As a result, arbiters affect the definition of majority, in order to help prevent rollback."

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is off topic at Stackoverflow, which is aimed at _programming_ questions. The proper place to ask is http://dba.stackexchange.com. Please ask there and delete your question here.

Comment: You put w:majority, w:number, or use tags in a code/config. Answer to this question will affect developers code. I would disagree with Markus that this is DBA question.

Comment: I am actually unsure if the arb will just ack wtihout actually doing anything or will throw an error on the write. I need to test

Comment: @Sammaye : do you mean an arbiter will receive documents, even if it does not hold any data ? Mongo protocol doesn't handle the specificity of the arbiter ?

Comment: Since the arb is used to garnish majority vote in your scenario I wonder if the protocol would count it as a data holding hold when commiting write concern, logically it shouldn't but...of course in the case where you have 1 node and 2 arbs it means you are not writing to majority anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a 5 member (4 data bearing, one arbiter) replica set, each member having one vote, a majority is 3. Therefore, `w : majority` means a write needs to wait for ack from 3 nodes before returning successfully. Only nodes that replicate the write can ack it - the arbiter increases the number of nodes for majority because it has a vote but cannot help fulfill majority because it isn't data bearing. If 2/4 data bearing nodes are down, then you cannot get 3 acks, so writes with `w:majority` cannot succeed and will time out and fail.

Why does the arbiter count for determining majority? Rollback. The key guarantee of `w:majority` is that, if a write is ack'd with `w:majority`, then it will not be rolled back during failover. Including the arbiter in the count for majority is necessary for this guarantee.

Comment: Good to know, I was just about to setup a test envo to find out what actually happens. Though that last paragraph: if the arb has no data then couldn't a rollback occur since the majority is not actually written? It seems pointless to count non-data holding nodes in that

Comment: Rollback won't occur because w:majority guarantees the new primary will have received (and ack'd) the write if the write returned successfully. No matter how you partition the replica set due to failures, if a majority can talk to each other, at least one of them acked on a w:majority write. Since the oplog is linearly ordered and elections prefer the most up-to-date member, this means the new primary will have the write, hence no rollback. You can play around with the 4 data-bearing, 1 arb setup to see this, and see it fails to work if there's 3 data bears, 2 arbs, and "majority" meant 2.

Comment: OK, I guess if you had a majority that was all arbiters...but disregard that